# printing dump or dd when doing ajax post I was able to preview the answer in the chrome, not anymore

Tags: laravel, google-chrome

I am doing some debuging from the server and I was able to previously get a preview in the google chrome network tab, what ever server answered would get rendered clearly if I used dd() or dump()

now all I get is bunch of html and I can't make anything out.

You can see here what I see

[image]

This stuff used to be like this if I went to Response tab instead of Preview tab, but now even Preview tab does not make any sense.

Never had a problem with this before. Anyone else noticed or had this problem? How to debug a problem I have on server when I can't dd or dump to inspect what went wrong with save operation?

Comment: In which context are you calling `dd()`? Show the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML you are seeing looks like the default markup of the error page. You could check the `storage/logs/laravel.log` file to see whats causing the error